# Change active View Layer with Python

Tags: python, rendering, 3d-view, viewlayers

I'm currently trying to figure out how i can change the active view layer with python. The change to 2.8 made sourcing for documentation quite difficult.

I'd be thankfull for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Set `Window.view_layer`**

From https://code.blender.org/2017/09/view-layers-and-collections/

> For simplicity now, we stick to having a single ‘active View Layer’
>   per Blender window.

Set the `view_layer` property of the context window to the view layer you wish to be active for that window.

Example using py console. I have 3 viewlayers "RenderLayer", "View Layer" and "XXXX", code below sets "XXXX" as active in current (context) window.

```
>>> vl = C.scene.view_layers['
                              RenderLayer']
                              View Layer']
                              XXXX']
>>> vl = C.scene.view_layers['XXXX']
>>> C.window.view_layer = vl
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was far simpler than i imagined. Its essentially just: bpy.context.window.view_layer = bpy.context.scene.view_layers ['Layer_Name']

Comment: Possibly worth noting used to set context scene via `context.screen.scene = scn`, now that is also done via window also.  `context.window.scene = scn`.

Comment: sorry, that was just a misclick. It showed me that there has been an edit, so i've reloaded the page. After that it must have been unset again. Sorry!

Comment: Cheers, didn't think it could be from changing "Render Layer" to "RenderLayer" lol.

Comment: haha :D that would be quite harsh