# Create/Remove View Layer and give it names

Tags: python, scripting

How to create ViewLayer and set name for it using Python? And don't do this if the layer already exists. My code removes the active layer, but it needs to be removed *by name*. And after this need be active first layer. In this case I create an blank layer (type='EMPTY').

In the end it should be this

1. Create an empty layer if it doesn't exist
2. Give it a name
3. The main layer should remain selected

My not finished code:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

bpy.ops.scene.view_layer_remove()
bpy.ops.scene.view_layer_add(type='EMPTY')
bpy.context.window.view_layer.name = 'Sample'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest ditching the operators which are notoriously hard to use and override, and deal directly with the data.

```
import bpy

if "Sample" not in bpy.context.scene.view_layers:
    bpy.context.scene.view_layers.new("Sample")
    layer_collections = [bpy.context.scene.view_layers[-1].layer_collection]
    # Here we exclude all the view layer collections so it mimicks the "BLANK" option
    while layer_collections:
        l_c = layer_collections.pop(0)
        layer_collections.extend(l_c.children)
        l_c.exclude = True
```

If you want to use an operator you can use this

```
import bpy

if "Sample" not in bpy.context.scene.view_layers:
    previous_view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
    bpy.ops.scene.view_layer_add(type='EMPTY')
    bpy.context.view_layer.name = 'Sample'

    # Restore the previous view layer since the operator changes the active view layer
    bpy.context.window.view_layer = previous_view_layer
```

Link to [bpy.types.ViewLayer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html) docs.

Link to [bpy.types.Scene.view_layers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.view_layers) docs and the [definition](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayers.html#bpy.types.ViewLayers).

[How to change the active view layer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131883/86891)

Comment: Okay, let's say 6 lines is better than 1 line.

But why immediately remove the newly created layer in the second part of the code? Need delete named Blank Layer if it exits(where is If?). It is logical to assume that there should be a main layer, and a Blank Layer should be added to it, provided that it does not exist, and the main one should remain selected.

In addition, the code throws an error if a non-existent (or already deleted) layer is entered on the layer to be deleted.

Comment: Well you say it's logicial but there are as many workflows as there are people using Blender, so I simply answered your question based on your code snippet and your explanations. If that doesn't fullfill your need, feel free to discard of fill in the blanks, otherwise sorry but I just don't understand what you're trying to do :)

Comment: 1) Create an empty layer if it doesn't exist
2) Give it a name
3) The main layer should remain selected

I have given an example of my code as **wrong**, because it deletes the **current** (Blank) layer and nothing happened. But need delete blank layer by name(if it exists of course) while remaining on the first layer and create again(for my variant "delete>create"), or another option in which at the end I will be on the first layer and blank will be created.

Comment: @M.Gordon okay, I think I got your three steps, I don't really get the end of your comment but that should get you started. :) Please see my revision.

Comment: Thanks for attention

Comment: do you can help me select view layer by name?

Comment: `bpy.context.scene.view_layers["name"]` or `bpy.data.scenes["scene_name"].view_layers["name"]`

Comment: Thank you very much!